# How to make a defensive copy of a SettableFuture? Or generally a ListenableFuture?

Tags: guava

Like [`CompletableFuture.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#copy--). Not sure if it makes sense for other `ListenableFuture`s, but at least for `SettableFuture`, I don't want an unauthorized client to set the future.

I'm thinking about using [`Futures.transform()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture-com.google.common.base.Function-java.util.concurrent.Executor-), which seems to create a chained `ListenableFuture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform(x -> x)` is a good solution -- and it sounds like an equivalent one to `copy()`.

The only caveat I can think of is that it's possible for updates to the two `Future` objects to race: It's possible for the original `Future` to complete and the other `Future` to be cancelled, in which case you have a "copy" with a different status. (Similarly, it's possible to observe one `Future` as completed while the other is still pending.) Again, this sounds like it's the case for `copy()`, too. If it concerns you, you can create a `ForwardingListenableFuture` that wraps the original `Future` instead.